# VueJS Router Active Link Style to all elements inside the router-link

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

In my sidebar, there are some `<router-link>`and I want their style is to be different when they are active. I am using `router active-class` for the `<router-link>` but the other elements inside the router-link are not taking some css properties. Here is my `<router-link>` looks like;

```
  <router-link tag="li" to="/dashboard" class="nav-item has-treeview" active-class="active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="dashboard_tab">
      <i class="sidebar-icons">dashboard</i>
      <p class="sidebar-links" active-class="active-p">Dashboard</p>
    </a>
  </router-link>
```

And here is my `.active` class;

```
.active {
  background-color: #FF7400;
  border-color: #FF7400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
}
```

Now when a specific link is clicked and active, I have orange background and some border around that router-link. But my problem is, I also want the color of the `icon` and the `p` element is to be white, but they are not being effected by the `color: white;` property. What am I missing? `active-class` is only working for the `router-link` element so I cannot use it in the `i` or `p`. What should i do?

Comment: Try `.active a { color: white }`

Comment: Oh you're right, I haven't tried that. Thanks for the support!

Comment: It's not necessary to use an `a` tag inside `router-link`